# SUMPRODUCT with calculated criteria over column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Excel-Table:**

```
       A           B            C             D           E            F         G       H    
1  Products       Date        Sales     Criteria 1:   Product_B      Result:    200
2  Product_A    2020-04-15     500      Criteria 2:   2020-04-15    
3  Product_B    2020-04-12     600              
4  Product_B    2020-04-12     300              
5  Product_B    2020-04-15     200              
6  Product_B    2020-04-20     400              
7  Product_C    2020-04-15     800              
8  Product_C    2020-04-19     900              
9  Product_C    2020-04-30     300              
10
11
```

In the table above I have different `products` and their `sales` on a certain `date`. 
In `Cell G1` I calculate sum of the sales based on the criterias in `Cell E1` and `E2`.

```
G1 = SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$100=$E$1)*($B$2:$B$100=$E$2)*$C$2:$C$100))
```

All this works exactly as it should.

---

Now, I want to change the `date condition` in the formula in `Cell G1`:

If in `Column B` a `date + 3 days` matches with the date in `Cell E2` it should be considered in the sum for `Cell G1`.

Expected Result in `Cell G1` would be `900`.

---

How do I need to modify the `SUMPRODUCT` formula in `Cell G1` to use the calculated criteria `date + 3 days = E2` over `Column B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$100=$E$1)*($B$2:$B$100=($E$2-3))*$C$2:$C$100))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

`=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$9,$A$2:$A$9,$E$1,$B$2:$B$9,$E$2-3)`

`$C$2:$C$9`: The range with the Sales

`$A$2:$A$9`: The range with the Products

`$E$1`: Product as criteria

`$B$2:$B$9`: The range with the Dates

`$E$2-3`: Date as criteria

Also you could use the `SUMPRODUCT`

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$100=$E$1)*($B$2:$B$100=$E$2-3)*($C$2:$C$100))`

**Note:**

I think you use too many brackets in your formula. Enclose each `Array` in brackets and one set of brackets for the whole formula.